# 3.4 Python changing image position tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a small pop up to a text game I am making. I just want a small frame to pop up with some text and a picture to the far left but in a custom size and position. How would I do this? How do I insert text and change the image position and size, this is my current code, it works as in there are no errors and the image shows.

```
from tkinter import * 

import time, sys


root = Tk()
root.configure(background='#16e116')
root.title('Pop Up')
root.geometry('300x200')
photo = PhotoImage(file='file.gif')
w = Label(root, image=photo)
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your image to be a different size (without it being deformed by resizing the widget) you have to make it the desired size in your image editor.

If you want to change the image position then use `grid()` where `pack()` has very limited placement options.

If you want text on a label, then use: `text = Label(root, text="Hello world!")`. This also comes with various options and styles such as `font` and it's size.

If you want the text over the image then use `grid()` and place it in the middle of the image by using rows and columns.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.configure(background='#16e116')
root.title('Pop Up')
root.geometry('300x200')

photo = PhotoImage(file='file.gif')

w = Label(root, image=photo)
text = Label(root, text="Hello world!")

w.grid(row=3, column=3)
text.grid(row=3, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Although, the label will still have the background around it but you change the background colour using `widgetname.config(bg="Colour")`to make it suit your standards.

Now of course, I can't be sure the above will work because I don't have `file.gif` but you should also read tutorials before jumping straight into code to avoid confusion.